# how to port this bit of code from HOWL vocoder synth from AudioKit 2 to AudioKit 4.x?

Tags: audiokit

I'm trying to port the HOWL vocoder synth from AudioKit 2 to the latest version. 
https://github.com/dclelland/HOWL

I'm starting with the Vocoder:

https://github.com/dclelland/HOWL/blob/master/HOWL/Models/Audio/Vocoder.swift

I'm not sure how this next bit of code works. 
Is the reduce() applying the resonant filter to the audio input in a consecutive manner? Is it doing the equivalent of `AKResonantFilter(AKResonantFilter(AKResonantFilter(mutedInput)))) ?`

Or is something else going on?

```
let mutedAudioInput = AKAudioInput() * AKPortamento(input: inputAmplitude, halfTime: 0.001.ak)

    let mutedInput = (input + mutedAudioInput) * AKPortamento(input: amplitude, halfTime: 0.001.ak)

    let filter = zip(frequencies, bandwidths).reduce(mutedInput) { input, parameters in
        let (frequency, bandwidth) = parameters
        return AKResonantFilter(
            input: input,
            centerFrequency: AKPortamento(input: frequency, halfTime: 0.001.ak),
            bandwidth: AKPortamento(input: bandwidth, halfTime: 0.001.ak)
        )
    }
```

here is my attempt at porting the vocoder filters:

```
import AudioKitPlaygrounds
import AudioKit
import AudioKitUI

let mixer = AKMixer()
let sawtooth = AKTable(.sawtooth)
let sawtoothLFO = AKOscillator(waveform: sawtooth, frequency: 130.81, amplitude: 1, detuningOffset: 0.0, detuningMultiplier: 0.0)
let frequencyScale = 1.0


let topFrequencies = zip(voice.æ.formants,voice.α.formants).map {topLeftFrequency,topRightFrequency in
            return 0.5 * (topRightFrequency - topLeftFrequency) + topLeftFrequency
        }

let bottomFrequencies = zip(voice.i.formants,voice.u.formants).map {bottomLeftFrequency,bottomRightFrequency in
            return 0.5 * (bottomRightFrequency - bottomLeftFrequency) + bottomLeftFrequency
        }
let frequencies = zip(topFrequencies, bottomFrequencies).map { topFrequency, bottomFrequency in
            return (0.5 * (bottomFrequency - topFrequency) + topFrequency) * frequencyScale
        }
let bandwidthScale = 1.0
let bandwidths = frequencies.map { frequency in
            return (frequency * 0.02 + 50.0) * bandwidthScale
        }

let filteredLFO = AKResonantFilter(sawtoothLFO)
let filter = zip(frequencies,bandwidths).reduce(filteredLFO) { input,parameters in
            let (frequency, bandwidth) = parameters
            return AKResonantFilter(
                input,
                frequency: frequency,
                bandwidth: bandwidth
            )

        }
[filter, sawtoothLFO] >>> mixer
filter.start()
sawtoothLFO.play()
```

I am getting some sound but it isn't quite right. I am not sure if I am taking the right approach.

In particular my question is : is this the right approach to rewriting the bit of code highlighted above?

```
let filteredLFO = AKResonantFilter(sawtoothLFO)
let filter = zip(frequencies,bandwidths).reduce(filteredLFO) { input,parameters in
            let (frequency, bandwidth) = parameters
            return AKResonantFilter(
                input,
                frequency: frequency,
                bandwidth: bandwidth
            )

        }
```

Is there a more preferred way to do this whole thing, using AKOperation generators? Should I be using AKFormantFilter ?  I've experimented with AKFormantFilter and AKVocalTract, but have not been able to get the audio results I wanted. The HOWL app pretty much sounds exactly like what I'm trying to do, which is why I started porting the code. (it's for a "talking" robot game)

Comment: Hey Chester.  Porting HOWL has been on my list of things to do for over a year now.  And its especially important now as the last time I tried the app it doesn't work - not sure which version of iOS broke it.  In any event, would you like have an account on the AudioKit Slack group to get immediate access to people who could help?

Comment: An account on AudioKit Slack sounds cool. I sent you an email.